# Does “Reset your PC” option result in the same exact version of Windows 10 I currently have with updates, or Windows 10 with no updates?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface

Does the “[Reset your PC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-refresh-reset-or-restore-your-pc-51391d9a-eb0a-84a7-69e4-c2c1fbceb8dd)” option *[Link here first references Windows 8. Click on link and follow references to Windows 10 edited by @John]* result in the same exact version of Windows 10 I currently have with updates, or Windows 10 with no updates?

In other words, let’s say I bought a Microsoft Surface a couple years ago with Windows 10 on it (let's call it Windows v10.0).

Whenever I install an update, it increments by 0.1.

So now let’s say I'm currently at Windows v10.8.

If I do a “Reset your PC” option, will it revert back to Windows v10.0? Or will I still have Windows v10.8?

My goal is actually to revert back to Windows v.10.0.

Would appreciate all / any advice from the expert Microsoft community.

Comment: “do you know how I can bring it back to an early copy of Windows 10 without any updates?” - It’s impossible to downgrade your build number without a complete reinstall of Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset is a form of Repair Install. It keeps your data (and therefore your User Profile) so then (and I am quite sure about this), it will bring your system up to the current level of Windows 10 (whatever the "level" is when you run the reset.

Reset is not a factory reload.

If you start with an earlier version (factory reload), Windows 10 will start updating immediately. I have done this.

You cannot keep Windows 10 permanently at an old level. It will eventually update.

Comment: @user1068636 - Your link contains inaccurate information.

Comment: I edited the question to note that the link provided can quickly lead to Windows 10 Information.  It was a Microsoft Article.